# How to fix "Input string was not in a correct format" error in G1ANT Studio?

Tags: rpa, g1ant

I am trying to the have G1ANT Studio copy cells from on google docs sheet to another. I keep getting the "Input string was not in a correct Format" Error when trying to copy the value of the cells A1, B1 and C1 from one sheet to the other.

Here is the code:

```
addon googledocs version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

googlesheet.open 1tHiVE0ALnIixrHm3rDyxQQhLMUiZCzu5KS8Pkg1eGAo result ♥testSheetId
googlesheet.getvalue A1&B1&C1 result ♥values
dialog ♥values
googlesheet.open 1ZoeFnqAu1v_agEdG6mdcTgaDhlxmn8gXbSY7PF0TMvg result ♥emptySheetId
googlesheet.switch ♥emptySheetId
googlesheet.setvalue range A1 value ♥values⟦1⟧
googlesheet.setvalue range B1 value ♥values⟦2⟧
googlesheet.setvalue range C1 value ♥values⟦3⟧
```

I keep getting the "Input string was not in a correct Format" Error when trying to copy the value of the cells A1, B1 and C1 from one sheet to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code from `googlesheet.setvalue range A1 value ♥values⟦1⟧` to `googlesheet.setvalue range A1 numeric false value ♥values⟦1⟧`, it is now able to identify the right type.

Comment: You have a typo, argument should be "numeric" but yes, it is the right solution :)